# Entity Framework - AddOrUpdate using Linq and Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have defined a settings class using the following code:

```
    public Setting(string settingName, string settingValue, bool delay = false)
    {
        if (delay)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        CreatedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        SettingName = settingName;
        SettingValue = settingValue;
    }
```

In a settings controller I have defined a dictionary with KeyValuePairs for settingsName and settingValue. Using a foreach loop I want to iterate over the dictionary creating a new setting for each entry. I am trying the following code, however it throws an `TargetInvocationException`:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> setting in settings)
        {
            var temp = new Setting(setting.Key, setting.Value);
            _appContext.Settings.AddOrUpdate(x => 
                new {x.Id}, temp);
        }

        _appContext.SaveChanges();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason may be that there are no empty constructor.
Try define empty constructor for class `Setting`.

```
[Obsolete("Only for serialization", true])
public Setting()
{
}
```

you prevent using that constructor in code using the `[Obsolete]` attribute.

Comment: You forgot a closing parenthesis, but otherwise spot on! Works like a charm. I can't believe my code was actually correct ;))